# Thread name not shown in info thread command when using gdb 7.7

Tags: gdb

In some of the answers to related questions I could see that gdb 7.3 should support displaying thread names atleast with 'info threads' command .
But I am not even getting that luxury. please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

My sample code  used for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
static pthread_t ta, tb;

void *
fx (void *param)
{ 
    int i = 0; 
    prctl (PR_SET_NAME, "Mythread1", 0, 0, 0); 
    while (i < 1000) 
       { 
         i++; 
         printf ("T1%d ", i); 
        } 
} 

void * 
fy (void *param) 
{ 
  int i = 0; 
  prctl (PR_SET_NAME, "Mythread2", 0, 0, 0); 
  while (i < 100) 
    { 
      i++; 
      printf ("T2%d ", i); 
    } 
  sleep (10); 
  /* generating segmentation fault */ 
  int *p; 
  p = NULL; 
  printf ("%d\n", *p); 

} 

int 
main () 
{ 


  pthread_create (&ta, NULL, fx, 0); 
  pthread_create (&tb, NULL, fy, 0); 

  void *retval; 
  pthread_join (ta, &retval); 
  pthread_join (tb, &retval); 

  return 0; 
}
```

Output( using core dump generated by segmentation fault)

```
(gdb) core-file core.14001 
[New LWP 14003]
[New LWP 14001]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./thread_Ex'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x08048614 in fy (param=0x0) at thread_Ex.c:30
30  printf("%d\n",*p);
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  2    Thread 0xb77d76c0 (LWP 14001) 0x00b95424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
* 1    Thread 0xb6dd5b70 (LWP 14003) 0x08048614 in fy (param=0x0) at thread_Ex.c:30
(gdb) bt
#0  0x08048614 in fy (param=0x0) at thread_Ex.c:30
#1  0x006919e9 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x005d3f3e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb77d76c0 (LWP 14001)):
#0  0x00b95424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x006920ad in pthread_join () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x080486a4 in main () at thread_Ex.c:50

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb6dd5b70 (LWP 14003)):
#0  0x08048614 in fy (param=0x0) at thread_Ex.c:30
#1  0x006919e9 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x005d3f3e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) q
```

As you can see I cant see any thread names that I have set. what could be wrong?

Note:
I am using gdb version 7.7 (Downloaded and compiled using no special options) 
commands used to compile & install gdb : ./configure && make && make install

Comment: with my system (gdb 7.6, xf86_64) I can see thread names only when live debugging. Using it for post-mortem analysis as you are doing, thread names don't show up

Comment: I tried to start the elf from gdb directly.Yet I dont see any thread names showing up. I will try version 7.6 as well.

Comment: @Sigismondo    I tried using 7.6, no luck. I am not sure what I am missing(I am using 32 bit version)

Comment: I just used Fedora19 gdb - out-of-the-box, it worked fine with your test code, compiled with just "gcc -g".

Comment: it works in ubuntu. I tried with ubuntu 14.04 which comes pre installed with gdb7.7. But my CentOS is not giving the same result with my own gdb7.7 compiled version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, thread names are not present in the core dump.

If they are available somehow, please file a gdb bug.

Comment: How can I confirm if thread names are present in core dump or not?

Comment: [root@Serv Threads]# grep -inr MyThread2 core.5546 
Binary file core.5546 matches

Comment: It might match if the string appears in the heap.  I suppose the best way would be to dig up the documentation or perhaps the relevant kernel source code.

Comment: I thunk you are right .it has to do more with core file generation than gdb since it works on live debugging

Answer (score 0):

I get thread name displayed on CentOS6.5, but not displayed on CentOS6.4 .